# Apple Mach-o error linked

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I get this error and I have no idea why out, apparently my libraries are well linked

```
  ...
"_equalTo", referenced from:
  -[FBFacebookAppAuthenticationTests testImplFacebookAppAuthSuccessWithBehavior:] in FBFacebookAppAuthenticationTests.o
  -[FBGraphObjectTests testCanSetProperty] in FBGraphObjectTests.o
  -[FBGraphObjectTests testInsertObjectAtIndex] in FBGraphObjectTests.o
  -[FBGraphObjectTests testAddObject] in FBGraphObjectTests.o
```

etc...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fabie.png

Comment: missing an image perhaps?

Comment: on my level user has not let me post images :(

Comment: I was referring to this in the beginning of your question: "![enter image description here][1]"

Comment: Since this, I've edited out the link there image have if you can help me, thanks

Comment: The warning that the linker has given you... does the directory actually exist? Were you expecting something in it to provide the ACFacebook symbols?

Comment: If I have linked to the desktop, this problem arose after including libraries that had been on the project but on the other mac and open them were no longer here ... the issue of the I have directories like this:

Framework search paths: $ (inherited) "$ (DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR)"
headers search paths: $ (inherited) "$ (SRCROOT) / nameaplication / Twitter + OAuth / Libraries & Headers" "$ (SRCROOT) / nameaplication/evernote-ios-sdk/UnitTests/3rdParty/OCMock" "$ (SRCROOT) / nameaplication "